# Using one color to draw a triangle stored inside a buffer opengl es 2.0

Tags: colors, buffer, opengl-es-2.0

I am drawing many different triangles with one draw call `glDrawElements`.
I am storing the vertices inside a buffer with `glBufferData`.

I can now give each triangle a different color by storing the color data inside the same buffer i store the vertices. I can then use `glVertexAttribPointer` to tell opengl where the colors are. Inside the vertex shader i define an attribute and then copy it to a varying in order to pass it to the fragment shader.

This means that I have to define a color for each vertex of the triangle. So i have to define 3 colors, but I only need 1 color for each triangle.

Is there a way to do this more efficient? Does it even matter? Can I store 1 color for each triangle inside a server side buffer?

Comment: In OpenGL ES 3.2 there would be the possibility to get the index of the current primitive by the built in variable [`gl_PrimitiveID`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3/html/gl_PrimitiveID.xhtml) in the fragment shader. The ID can be used to get the color from a 1 dimension a texture or shader storage buffer.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i will not use 3.2 only 2.0, i think what i want might not be possible and I should just go with one color for each vertex, instead of one color for each triangle.

Comment: Oh yes of course, it is not possible with OpenGL ES 2, as far as I know. Perhaps some one else has an idea...